# Django select count of same foreign keys within the same model

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, django-orm

I have this model:

```
class Content(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, blank=False, primary_key=True, unique=True)

class File(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=21, null=False, blank=False,
                          primary_key=True, unique=True)
    id_content = models.ForeignKey(Content, db_column="id_content",
                                   on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I want to select the `id` and the count of other files with the same Foreign Key as this `id`. I literally have got no clue about where to define such query inside `filter`, `extra` etc.

I have done this previously inside this `MySQL` query, but I'm looking for a Django Model solution:

```
SELECT
    f1.`id` AS id,
    (SELECT COUNT(f2.`id_content`)
     FROM `file` AS f2 WHERE f2.`id_content` = f1.`id_content`) AS total
FROM
    `file` AS f1;
```

Comment: What do you currently have? An `id` or a `File` object?

Comment: Currently, I haven't built any statement, waiting for a query to count the same foreign key. Currently, I only have this:

`File.objects.all().values("id")`

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `File` object (e.g. `my_file`):

```
my_file.id_content.file_set.count()
```

if you only know the `id` you should `get` the `File` instance first:

```
my_file = File.objects.get(id=id)
```

and apply the first method.

That being said, do not start your `ForeignKey` field names with `id_`. It makes your code confusing. It would be a better practice to name it `content`, i.e.

```
content = models.ForeignKey(Content, ...)
```

Comment: I have updated my post and defined the Content model. Hope that helps.

I just want to print the `id` and count of same foreign keys same time as my MySQL Query.

``